# Having Multiple network connections in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, networking, virtual-machine, vmware

I have doubt with network connections and i want to clear it. I want to how how multiple connection work.

Suppose i have 3 network adapters in my virtual machine

```
Eth0: is the host only network with vmware and my vm windows 7
Eth1: is the bridged network with IP direct from my router
COnn3: is th3 VPN connection to office
```

1. I want to know that if i use internet, through which network it will go
2. DO all connections work simultaniously or or only one is active at one time
3. What about shared folders. I mean if i have shared folders in all connections. will i be able to see them all.
4. Also if i have web server on Vm through which network i can access it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple network connections on Windows 7](http://superuser.com/questions/313679/multiple-network-connections-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It will go to the wired connection, or the top-most connection on the connection settings.
2. They work one at a time, but with tools like [Connectify](http://www.connectify.me/), you can access more than one connection simultaneously.
3. If you are connected via LAN you can access shared folders in different computers. If you are connected to a wireless connection, you can access those that are connected to that wireless and have provided you access to their shared folders.
4. If that web server has ftp access, you can access it through windows explorer or any other tool for ftp access. Every connection that provides you internet connection can give you access to it. In case you manage the server yourself and are connected through it via LAN, you can connect to it via your LAN connection.

In case that I did not make things clear, or something is wrong, please let me know.